# What abilities can be stopped with taunts/silences/knock-ups etc?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering what abilities can be stopped with casting a taunt, knock-up, pull etc. I know that when Shen uses his shadow dash while Karthus is channeling his Requiem it will cancel Karthus his Requiem. Now i main Darius and naturally i was wondering if it was possible to taunt(, knock-up, pull etc) Darius while he uses his Noxian Guillotine to cancel the ability. Then i wondered since that might be possible what other abilities that have even the slightest of casting animation could be stopped by taunting, knocking-up, pulling, silencing, etc. Think Nunu ult, Jarvan ult (if you taunt while he is jumping?), Twisted Fate ult, Shen ult, Fiora ult, etc.

Since this part of the question expanded it by quite a bit what would be the criteria of canceling an ability. If an ability animation gets past a certain point in which it cant  be stopped, instead of a milisecond earlier when it could be stopped?

Comment: Abilities that are considered as 'dash' (Tris rocket jump, Shyv's ult) are often vulnerable to be cancelled while 'flash-like' (Shaco's deceive, Fiddle's ult) are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if an ability is described as "channeling" then it can be interrupted.

For example Fiddlesticks channels for a short while before starting Crowstorm, Karthus channels his Requiem, Malzahar and Warwick both channel their ultimates, etc.

Additionally abilities that dash such as Tristana's Rocket Jump, Corki's Valkyrie, etc can usually be interrupted. Malphite's Unstoppable Force explicitly says that it cannot be interrupted.

Most other abilities cannot be interrupted except by removing the target. For example Zhonya's hourglass will prevent the Darius Ultimate but taunting him will not. He would instead be taunted once the Ultimate animation completes.